# Cloud Run: cannot remove secret and add environment variable with same name using gcloud CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Can someone tell me how I can use the `gcloud run deploy` to remove a secret attached to the Cloud Run service and add a new environment variable with the same as the secret?

I have a Cloud Run service which is configured to use a secret (let's call the secret `SOME_CONFIG`) as an environment variable at runtime. When I try to use `gcloud run deploy` to remove the secret, and add an environment variable with the same name as the secret that was removed (`SOME_CONFIG`) I get the following error,

> (gcloud.run.services.update) Cannot update environment variable [SOME_CONFIG] to string literal because it has already been set with a different type.

I intend to do this change using the `gcloud run deploy` command as a build step on Cloud Build.

I tried using both `remove-secrets` and `update-env-vars` like below,

`gcloud run services update ats-integrations-service-stage --remove-secrets=SOME_CONFIG --update-env-vars=SOME_CONFIG=some_value`

This didn't succeed as I got the same error as above.

Comment: It could not work in the same command. Try to do it in 2 successives deployments

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that is how I got by for now, doing it manually. However, we manage our infrastructure as code and we want such changes to be applied automatically. Currently, we use Cloud Build (cloudbuild.yaml) to configure and deploy the Cloud Run service.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the CLI. Did you try to achieve that by using `gcloud run services replace` and passing the full Cloud Run service description (in Knative format). I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think it would work too, but I didn't try it because most examples on Google Cloud docs demonstrate using `gcloud run deploy` in `cloudbuild.yaml` to deploy. Is it preferable to use the `gcloud run services replace` with the KNative config file over `gcloud run deploy` in a Cloud Build? Any drawbacks or docs/examples on it?

Comment: Indeed, it's easiest to use the `gcloud run deploy` command, especially to deploy a new container version with a tag. It's simply an argument in the command. If you use the `gcloud run services replace`, you have to update the YAML file with the image, and file manipulation to replace string is more cumbersome that changing a CLI parameter.